# Extract "words" from a string

Tags: r

I have a table with 153 rows by 9 columns. My interest is the character string in the first column, I want to extract the fourth word and create a new list from this fourth word, this list will be 153 rows, 1 column.

An example of the first two rows of column 1 of this database table:

```
[1] Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428
[2] Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353
```

"Words" are separated by spaces, so the fourth word of the first row is "428" and the fourth word of the second row is "353". How can I create a new list containing the fourth word of all 153 rows?

Comment: Aren't you just extracting the numbers? E.g, wouldn't this be just `gsub("\\D", "", x)`? Or `gsub(".* (\\d+)", "\\1", x)` maybe? Or if this always the last part, maybe `gsub(".*\\s+(.*)", "\\1", x)` too.

Comment: Is the fourth word always a number?

Comment: @DavidArenburg   The fourth "word" is usually, but not always, a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub()` with a regular expression

```
x <- c("Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428", "Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353")
ptn <- "(.*? ){3}"
gsub(ptn, "", x)

[1] "428" "353"
```

This works because the regular expression `(.*? ){3}` finds exactly three `{3}` sets of characters followed by a space `(.*? )`, and then replaces this with ane empty string.

See `?gsub` and `?regexp` for more information.

---

If your data has structure that you don't mention in your question, then possibly the regular expression becomes even easier.

For example, if you are always interested in the last word of each line:

```
ptn <- "(.*? )"
gsub(ptn, "", x)
```

Or perhaps you know for sure you can only search for digits and discard everything else:

```
ptn <- "\\D"
gsub(ptn, "", x)
```

Comment: Or `sub(".* (\\w+)$", "\\1", x)`?

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I think I'm going to have to learn more about gsub and regexp

Answer (score 2):

You could use `word()` from the `stringr`package:

```
> x <- c("Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428", "Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353")
> library(stringr)
> word(string = x, start = 4, end = 4)
[1] "428" "353"
```

Specifying the position of both the start and end words to be the same, you will always get the fourth word.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to get stringr to work in R 3.2.4 Revised :( (Windows 7 64 bit if that matters)

Comment: @Paige: Can you provide some more details? Does it throw any error and if yes, what is it? I did it in 3.2.4 in Windows 7 (Professional) 64-bit as well, did not have any problems. Just did it in 3.2.4 under Arch Linux (64-bit) and had no problems. You can try reinstalling package `stringi` on which `stringr` depends (please note the very similar names, don't be confused - these are different packages) and try again.

Comment: I just tried again to install and use stringr. The error is: > library(stringr)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘magrittr’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘stringr’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I upgraded to R 3.2.5 for Windows, and now stringr appears to work properly

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`.  We match the pattern one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) that gets repeated 3 times (`{3}`) followed by word that is captured in a group (`(\\w+)`) followed by one or more characters.  We replace it by the second backreference.

```
sub("(\\S+\\s+){3}(\\w+).*", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "428" "353"
```

This selects by the nth word, so

```
 sub("(\\S+\\s+){3}(\\w+).*", "\\2", str2)
 #[1] "428" "353" "428"
```

---

Another option is `stri_extract`

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_last_regex(str1, "\\w+")
 #[1] "428" "353"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428", "Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353")
str2 <- c(str1, "Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428 something else")
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? A comment could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, the function `strsplit` can help you :

```
data <- c('Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428', 'Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353')
unlist(lapply(strsplit(data, ' '), function(x) x[4]))
[1] "428" "353"
```