# remove last n elements from a row in a dataframe

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove the last n elements of each row in a dataframe. The dataframe I'm working on (`head_col`) has one column and I wish to split this column into more columns - one holding the last element of the original, another holding the last two, and one holding the last three.

Through searching around I found very helpful topics such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694028/extract-words-from-a-string) and other related ones, but I am such a regex toy that I can't manage to rewrite the snipped so that it take the last two/three elements. I also tried to play around with packages like `stringi` and its `stri_extract_last_words`, but this also takes just the last word. Any pointers on if/how to use this very handy `stringi` function to get it to what I want would be very appreciated.

link to the source .xls file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1ftjwine8ekj65/Book2_1.xls?dl=0

```
library(data.table)
library(XLConnect)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

#load .xls
wb <- loadWorkbook('D:/MOMUT1/GIS_Workload/Other/alex/Book2_1.xls')
df <- readWorksheet(wb, 1, header = TRUE)

#remove NAs
df_final <- subset(df, !is.na(df$HEADLINE))

#take out HEADLINE column to work on
head_col <- data.table(df_final$HEADLINE)

#regex attempts
head_col_last_1 <- sub(".*\\s+", '', head_col$V1) # takes only last word
head_col_last_2 <- gsub(".*\\s+(.*)", "\\1", head_col$V1) #also takes only last word

#stringi attempt
head_col_last_1 <- data.frame(stri_extract_last_words(head_col$V1))
```

Comment: Do you want `head_col_last_1 <- str_extract(head_col$V1, "\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}(?=\\s*$)")`?

Comment: Yes, you beautiful wizard of a person, you! I have to learn this Chinese alphabet of a monster that is regex. I thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
head_col_last_1 <- str_extract(head_col$V1, "\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}(?=\\s*$)")
```

The pattern matches:

- `\\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}`  - one or two occurrences of

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?=\\s*$)` - that are followed with 0+ whitespaces and the end of string.