# Extract string trivially from a text in R

Tags: r, regex

## Using R:

1. How do we calculate n for each use case?
   n = No. of string in the text
2. How do we extract the string from a text given in the following use cases:

Text 1

Use case 1 (n=1)

Input: [AB]
Expected Output: (1x1 DF)
AB

Use case 2 (n=3)

Input : [AB],[BC],[A]
Expected Output: (3x1 DF)
AB
BC
A

Text 2

Use case 1 (n=1)

Input: "AB"
Expected Output: (1X1 DF)
AB

Use case 2 (n=2)

Input: "AB","B"
Expected Output: (2X1 DF)
AB
B

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(c('[AB]', '[AB],[BC],[A]', '"AB"', '"AB","B"'), "[A-Z]+")` returns all of the strings you expect, so `lengths(.)` (around that) returns the number of substrings within each.

Comment: Some good discussions on regular expressions (regex): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695534/3358272

Comment: What if the Use case looks like : [AB],[BC_zz],[C]?

Comment: Or just : [CD_x]

Comment: Use `"[A-Z_]+"` for the pattern. *Or* you can go the inverted route, excluding separators, perhaps `"[^][\"',]+"` (untested).

Comment: InVinci, I don't know how better to "generalize" a solution: with regexes, "general" can be good but often results in more complicated patterns ... and more complicated means more fragile. The code I suggested addressed the test cases you have in your question. If you have other cases that are significantly different, then you need to demonstrate the differences in the OP, and not rely on me to infer and guess what else could be present in your real  data. The best rule for regexes is "keep is simple", don't over-engineer unless/until you have a clear well-bounded need.

Comment: The general query is on the next comment by @ThomasIsCoding, that I asked for. Simple and Clear! Thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: (1) I didn't give you that downvote, though I understand why you suspect that. (2) *"I asked for"* is not clear, nowhere did you demonstrate anything other than upper-case letters. I'm glad you received the help you need, but my first code perfectly addressed your use cases. The fact that it did not fit your underlying need reflects on how you communicated the problem constraints, not my suggested code. (3) *I don't care*, in the sense that this does not upset me. I get frustrated when comments suggest weakness in the solution that are based on secret constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the code below is what you are after.

---

Assuming we have strings `s1` and `s2`

```
s1 <- "[AB],[B_C],[A]"
s2 <- '"A_B","B","C"'
```

and we apply

```
data.frame(s1 = regmatches(s1, gregexpr("\\w+", s1))[[1]])
data.frame(s2 = regmatches(s2, gregexpr("\\w+", s2))[[1]])
```

to get

```
> data.frame(s1 = regmatches(s1, gregexpr("\\w+", s1))[[1]])
   s1
1  AB
2 B_C
3   A

> data.frame(s2 = regmatches(s2, gregexpr("\\w+", s2))[[1]])
   s2
1 A_B
2   B
3   C
```